# How do I use shape keys to bake a soft body animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes, soft-body

I want to bake the soft body animation that can be placed in unity or unreal.
I also need the animation to loop. I know that you can you do loop key frames in graph editor. Is that possible with shape keys?

Comment: there is some issue with location transform, when origin is not set to 0,0,0. The imported mesh will be allocated.

Answer (score 4):

To convert a Soft Body animation into shape keys you can use the MDD importer/exporter. The Export option exports the soft body animation to a file and the Import option imports the file into a set of shape keys, along with keyframes to automatically control the shape keys to maintain the animation.

First, use the User Preferences option to enable the MDD importer/exporter addon by opening the Add-ons tab, typing 'MDD' into the search and enabling the Import-Export: NewTek MDD format add-on.

[image: addon]

Next, select your soft-body object and use the 'File/Export/Lightwave Point Cache (.mdd)' option, specifying a filename to export the animation to.

Once exported, use the 'File/Import/Lightwave Point Cache (.mdd)' option to import the animation. This will create a set of shapekeys with keyframes. The keyframes automatically adjust the shape keys influence so as to activate/deactivate them to animate through the frames of the animation. At this point you can remove the Soft Body simulation.

[image: shape keys]

You can adjust the keyframes on the shape keys to effectively 'blend' the animation at the start/end.

Here is a fantastic answer which uses a similar technique except that it uses a Mesh Cache modifier in place of the 'Import' step. By using two modifiers (with offset frames) the animation can be more easily blended at the start/end of the animation : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10661/29586

Comment: thank you so much!!! i got it to work! i really appreciate the answer!

Comment: @Ste I don't know about the speed of the mdd import/export, but you can also continuously [apply the modifier as a shapekey](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/107678/30849).

Comment: not at the computer right now but does the import add-on support cache with a stride? (saved every nth frame). Since it's a lot of shape keys, some simulations where nothing changes abruptly could use some interpolation

Comment: @NicolaSap Afraid not - although it would be feasible to write a script to remove all but every nth shape key and adjust the keyframing to blend between frames to interpolate.