# How do I get the armature/bones to fall with gravity?

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation

I cant get the mesh to **not** wig out after it falls.

I'm guessing I need the bones to fall with the mesh so the mesh deforms relative to the bones. I can't figure out how to do this and nothing I've googled has helped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Armature are not supported in context with the rigid body sytem.
The behaviour occurs, since the Armature is evaluated **after** the rigid body simulation. You can't change the order of evaluation (as in Maya e.g.).

**Shapekey** however, get evaluated *before* rigid bodies.

Use this hacky script to transfer your animation into shapekeys. (Refine it first, then use it!)
To make this script work, the active object:

- has to be selected
- has to have an Armature modifier name "Armature"
- has to have **no** Armature modifier name "Armature.001"
- has to have a "Basis" Shapekey

---

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.context.scene

frame_range = [1, 200]
for i in range(frame_range[0], frame_range[1] + 1):
    scn.frame_set(i)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_copy(modifier="Armature")
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='SHAPE', modifier='Armature.001')
    bpy.data.shape_keys["Key"].key_blocks["Armature.001"].name = str(i).zfill(3)


key = bpy.context.selected_objects[0].data.shape_keys.key_blocks


for i in range(frame_range[0], frame_range[1] + 1):
    key[str(i).zfill(3)].value = 0
    key[str(i).zfill(3)].keyframe_insert(data_path="value", frame=(i+1))
    key[str(i).zfill(3)].keyframe_insert(data_path="value", frame=(i-1))
    key[str(i).zfill(3)].value = 1
    key[str(i).zfill(3)].keyframe_insert(data_path="value", frame=i)
```

---

1. Disable the rigid body, by checking its animated property.
2. Create the Basis Shapekey.
3. Execute the script.
4. Hide the Armature modifier.

[image]

The animation is now transfered to shapekeys.

Disable the animated property again to simulate.

> If you wish to change the animation, delete all shapekeys and enable the armature modifier again.

Comment: looks like I'm getting a syntax error after running your script. Any thoughts? [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/V6naA9T)

Comment: @DavidSkillin The code had some incorrect linebreak due to a markdown error. It now has correct line breaks and indentation.

Comment: You wrote Animation modifier.  Did you intend to write Armature modifier?

Comment: @atomic Most definitely, thank you for notifiying me.