# Animating a Looping Soft Body Character

Tags: keyframes, soft-body

I started using Blender a couple days ago, after messing with Maya on and off for years.

I would like to make an animation with an ending frame that is exactly the same as the first frame for a gif so that it loops.  The object is a sheep which has wool and a soft body modifier. (I also have photoshop and I know how to make a gif using blender and photoshop).

So, I made a low poly sheep, rig, painted the weights, and then made a separate object for the sheep's wool. I painted the weights for that too. I added a soft body modifier, and I made it pretty stiff, I just wanted a very minor bounce affect to the movement in the wool.

However, I'm having a very hard time making a looping gif for it. I cannot add specific key frames with the soft body modifier... There is a small popping effect when the animation loops, because I can't get the wool on the sheep to return to a starting position. I thought I could make an ending key frame that is exactly the same as the first frame.

Any suggestions?

I'm also not committed to the soft body modifier. If there is another way to make the sheep's wool slightly bounce with movement using another modifier I don't mind trying that if I can have it loop.

Comment: Maybe you can apply [this technique](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/107678/30849) and turn your simulation into shapekeys. Then you can animated correct the shapekey influence manually. (Probably overly complicated, tag me if you can't get it to work.)

Comment: play with the graph editor for precision animating

Comment: Suggestion place an image of your work in the question.

Comment: @Leander I haven't worked with scripts before, where do I paste the script into? This looks like it might work. Also, do you have a discord account so I can chat with you there, in case I run into issues?

Comment: At least in blender, physics have a start and move forward, there is no support for ending at a specific shape so that it matches the beginning shape. Look at solutions offered for [looping cloth sims](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=loop+cloth).

Comment: @sambler Thanks for the confirmation. At least that means I didn't miss any settings or anything like that. I didn't have much understanding of the physics mechanics. Then, what'll be best if I just add extra bones into parts of the wool, and paint weights onto those, and animate that way. I can definitely have a starting position if I do it manually this way then. Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Physics have a start and end cycle, there is no way to "reset" the cycle once it starts calculating. My goal was set based on a limited knowledge of how the physics work. The best way to go about my goal of making a looping gif, with the wool moving, is to add extra bones and weight the wool to the bones, and animate it manually.

Alternatively, if the pose/animation allows for it, when creating the gif, reuse the images in reverse for the second half, to make the illusion that the wool is going back into place. This doesn't work for some animations, but it'll work for a basic standing position at least.